# Deleting core data object inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following piece of code inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. The code is used to delete an object from the `Core Data Store`  when satisfied some conditions.

I will try to explain my issue using one particular object:

App launch conditions for the object:

attribute `quitar = @"si"`

transient attribute `sectionIdentifier = @"0"`

If the user adds a new object to the section, then our example object gets following values:

attribute `quitar = @"si"`

transient attribute `sectionIdentifier = @"0"`

attribute `borrar = @"si se puede borrar"`;

The app makes what I expect, that means, the example object is deleted and the just added object is shown inside the section. 
But that is only partially true, then after checking the Core Data Store, the example object has change its attributes, but is not deleted.
That behaviour makes the app crash at the next app launch. If I launch the app again, the example object appears as deleted in the Core Data Store.

This is the exception message:

```
2014-02-14 11:32:27.033 DidIt[11267:a0b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableViewRowData rectForRow:inSection:heightCanBeGuessed:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UITableViewRowData.m:1793
2014-02-14 11:32:27.041 DidIt[11267:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for rect at invalid index path (<NSIndexPath: 0x8a22c00> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1})'
```

And this is my piece of code involved in the issue, as said it is inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
 //QUITAR SPECIAL ROW SECTION 0

        NSString *sec = todoitem.sectionIdentifier;
        NSString *quitar = todoitem.quitar;



        if ([sec isEqualToString:@"0"] && [quitar isEqualToString:@"si" ] && ( numObjectsSec0 > 1 ) ){

            NSLog(@"SE PODRIA QUITAR ESTE OBJETO *************************4 %@", todoitem.todoName);



            NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
            [todoitem setValue:@"si se puede borrar" forKey:@"borrar" ];
            has0SpecialRow = @"no";
             NSError *error = nil;
             // Save the object to persistent store
             if (![context save:&error]) {


                 [context deleteObject: todoitem];

             }




        }
        //END QUITAR SPECIAL ROW SECTION 0
```

Comment: I don't know what to think of that exception message, but deleting managed objects in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a **really** weird way to do things. It might help if you explained why you're doing this.

Comment: Thank you @TomHarrington, I will try to explain why am I doing this. In the tableView there are six fixed sections and I implemented also a way to expand/collapse the section rows. I detected exceptions when adding or deleting objects if there where empty sections. That made me create a mechanism that creates a new object on each section (I call it special row) if there are no rows (normal objects) on it.  Then when a normal object is created, then I use the above mentioned code to delete the special row. It was working fine until today, but I guess I have change something.

Comment: @TomHarrington, may be better using this code only to set the attribute value and then perform the deletion on another method?

Comment: @TomHarrington, I have solved it removing the line: [context deleteObject: todoitem]; and saving the object at another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue removing the lines:

```
  NSError *error = nil;
             // Save the object to persistent store
             if (![context save:&error]) {


                 [context deleteObject: todoitem];

             }
```

and putting the following code in the viewWillAppear method:

```
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;

    NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *fetch=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetch setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"borrar like 'si se puede borrar'"];
    [fetch setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *fetchError;
    NSArray *fetchedData=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError];
    for (NSManagedObject *item in fetchedData){

        [context deleteObject:item];
    }
```